# When printing out double dimensional array to console, values are being set randomly

Tags: c++, arrays

Let's say I create a double dimensional array in main fuction:

```
int board[8][8] = {0};
```

When I am printing it out to console with a simple FOR LOOP in MAIN everything works fine and console shows that all elements have been set to 0.

However, when I am trying to pass this array as an argument to the print function like shown below, some elements are set correctly to 0, whereas the rest become random values :

```
void print_board (int (*array)[8][8]);

int main (){

    int board[8][8] = {0};
    print_board(&board);

return 0;
} 

void print_board (int (*array)[8][8]){
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            cout << *array[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

I played with pointers and ampersands, and tried to google, but guess I am missing something.

Would be very grateful for your help!

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `operator[]` has higher precedence than `operator*`. So `*array[i][j]` is equivalent to `*(array[i][j])`. And `array` is a pointer (to array), and `array[i]` might cause UB when `i >= 1`.

You should change it to

```
cout << (*array)[i][j] << " ";
```

Comment: @watty Raw pointers ans raw arrays are confusing enough, and raw pointer + raw 2d array ... I'll sugguest you using `std::array` or `std::vector` to avoid them in "modern" C++.

Comment: I see. I guess I was trying to make it the hard way, whereas it could have been done much easier. Already corrected. Still thanks for the useful tip on operator precedences!

Answer (score 1):

You can change your output to `std::cout << (*array)[i][j]` or make things simpler:

```
void print_board(int array[8][8]){
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            std::cout << array[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}


int main (){
    int board[8][8] = {0};
    print_board(board);
}
```

Comment: Well that really made it easier... but at least I learned something new as well. Thanks a lot!